# Java objects to XML using javax.xml.bind.annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

If I have an object that contains a few fields that are Lists of other objects, and I want to generate the XML to represent that object, I get something like this

```
<top level object>
  <object1 />
  <object1 />
  <object1 /> 
  <object2 />
  <object2 />
  <object3 />
</top level object>
```

and I want to generate something like this:

```
<top level object>
  <object1 list>
    <object1 />
    <object1 />
    <object1 /> 
  </object1 list>
  <object2 list>
    <object2 />
    <object2 />
  </object2 list>
  <object3 />
</top level object>
```

Is this possible by modifying my annotations? Right now I have my top level class object marked with

```
 @XmlRootElement()
```

and each of the Object1, Object2...etc  getters  (that returns a List < Object#> )has the

```
@XmlElement()
```

annotation.

Hopefully there is a way to change my output by modifying the annotations, because it seems silly to me to make a "Object1List" object to simply hold a getter for the other lists to make this work the way I am picturing in my head

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `XmlElementWrapper` on [java.net](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_7-Wrapping-Repeated-Elements-XmlElementWrapper.html#Wrapping%20Repeated%20Elements:%20XmlElementWrapper) or in the [Java 6 API](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html).  I think that it is exactly what you are after.

Comment: This was exactly it. Thanks! I tried finding a list of hte annotations and I guess I missed that one, or missed how to use it at least

Comment: @Derek. That happens all of the time.  I think that most of the value of StackOverflow is it gives you access to what little details stuck in other peoples heads ;)